# AutoCAD eNotOpenForWrite

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I'm programming an AutoCAD plugin in C#.NET. I need a way to set `Table.IsReadEnabled` and `Table.IsWriteEnabled` to `true`. I have a method called `addRow()` shown here:

```
public void addRow(String[] data)
        {
            OpenCloseTransaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction();
            DocumentLock docLock = doc.LockDocument();
            using (tr)
            using (docLock)
            {
                bool isRead = IsReadEnabled;
                bool isWrite = IsWriteEnabled;

                BlockTable bt = (BlockTable)tr.GetObject(doc.Database.BlockTableId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(bt[Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace], OpenMode.ForWrite);

                selectedRow++; //Sets the lowest empty row as the one to be modified

                //Adding data to each cell
                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    Cells[selectedRow, i].SetValue(data[i], ParseOption.SetDefaultFormat);
                }
                GenerateLayout();

                //Attempting to update database with new data

                btr.AppendEntity(this);
                tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(this, true);

                tr.Commit();

            }
        }
```

The first time it adds data to my table it works fine but the `tr.Commit` call sets the table's `IsReadEnabled` and `IsWriteEnabled` to false even with an `OpenClose` transaction. That causes AutoCAD to crash when it tries to add a new row of data to the table. I need to either re-enable writing and reading after the `tr.commit` call or set it up so that writing and reading are never disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!IsWriteEnabled || !IsReadEnabled) //Committing transactions closes everything for reading and writing so it must be reopened
{
    tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForRead);
    tr.GetObject(this.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite);
}
```

I just needed to add an if statement!

Comment: I would love to except I can't for another 3 hours

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  `StartTransaction` instead of `StartOpenCloseTransaction`.  See attached blog.

Cheers,
Alain

http://spiderinnet1.typepad.com/blog/2012/08/autocad-net-openclosetransaction-can-it-be-nested.html

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this error happens when previous transaction is not properly disposed. 
The "addRow" function from the question is example of how not to code.
Always use the C# "using" statement to start transaction. It makes sure that transaction is disposed properly. Review and fix all places in your code where you start transaction.

```
using(OpenCloseTransaction tr = doc.TransactionManager.StartOpenCloseTransaction())
{
   // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try catch to get exact exception. Also transaction is missing.